# removing second layer for loop when defining array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, 2d

Working in MATLAB R2017a. I'm trying to optimise a piece of code I'm working on. It uses arrays to store field values on a grid. 
In order to create a specific function in a field array I originally used the straight forward method of two for loops iterating over all the array elements. But i know for loops are slow so since then I came back and tried my best to remove them. However I could only manage to remove one of the loops; leaving me with this:

```
for n = 1:1:K

%%% define initial pertubation 

t=n*dt;

% create array for source Ez field.

xtemps = (1:Ng)*dX;

for k = 1:Ng

    ztemp = k*dX;

    Ez0(k,:) = THzamp * (1/(1+exp(-(t-stepuppos)))) * exp(-((xtemps-...
    THzstartx).^2)./(bx^2)) .* (t-((ztemp-THzstartz)/vg))*exp(-((t-((ztemp-...
    THzstartz)/vg))^2)/(bt^2));

end
```

The important bit here is the last 5 lines, but I figured the stuff before might be important for context. I've removed the for loop looping over the x coordinates. I want to vectorize the z/k for loop but I can't figure out how to distinguish between the dimensions with the array oporators.

Edit: THzamp, stepuppos, bx, bt, THzstartz, THzstartx are all just scalars, they control the function (Ez0) I'm trying to create. dX and t are also just scalars. Ez0 is a square array of size Ng.

What I want to achieve is to remove the for loop that loops over k, so that that the values of ztemp are defined in a vector (like xtemps already is), rather than individually in the loop. However, I don't know how I'd write the definition of Ez0 in that case.

First time posting here, if I'm doing it wrong let me know. If you need more info just ask.

Comment: It would help if you at least defined the sizes of all your variables. This is very far from a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I've clearly not explained myself well enough. THzamp, stepuppos, bx, bt, THzstartz, THzstartx are all just scalars, they control the function (Ez0) I'm trying to create. dX and t are also just scalars. Ez0 is a square array of size Ng, What I want to achieve is to remove the for loop that loops over k, so that that the values of ztemp are defined in a vector (like xtemps already is), rather than individually in the loop. However, I don't know how I'd write the definition of Ez0 in that case. (I'm not sure how I'd make this a complete example without giving you my entire code, sorry)

Comment: I've just read, the link about complete examples. I can probably create something like that. Unfortunately I only have access to matlab at work so It'll have to wait until Tuesday. :/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear if `n` is used in the other headers and as stated in the comments your sizes aren't properly defined so you'll have to ensure the sizes are correct.

However, you can give this vectorize code a try.

```
n = 1:K

%%% define initial pertubation 

t=n*dt;

% create array for source Ez field.

xtemps = (1:Ng)*dX;

for k = 1:Ng

    ztemp = k*dX;

    Ez0(k,:) = THzamp .* (1./(1+exp(-(t-stepuppos)))) .* exp(-((xtemps-...
    THzstartx).^2)./(bx^2)) .* (t-((ztemp-THzstartz)/vg)).*exp(-((t-((ztemp-...
    THzstartz)/vg)).^2)/(bt.^2));

end
```

So now `t` has the size `K` you'll need to ensure `stepuppos`and `(ztemp-THzstartz)/vg)` have the same size `K`. Also you can take a look at vectors vs array operators [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk57v-1).

Comment: Sorry, I've clearly not explained myself well enough.

THzamp, stepuppos, bx, bt, THzstartz, THzstartx are all just scalars, they control the function (Ez0) I'm trying to create. dX and t are also just scalars.

Ez0 is a square array of size Ng, 

What I want to achieve is to remove the for loop that loops over k, so that that the values of ztemp are defined in a vector (like xtemps already is), rather than individually in the loop. However, I don't know how I'd write the definition of Ez0 in tat case.